# CKEditor загрузка изображения на сервер с буфера

Tags: php, сервер, изображения, ckeditor, загрузка

Установил плагин Upload Image для CKEditor 4.5.
Нужно при вставке в текстовое поле картинки с буфера - загружать ее на сервер и корректно отображать в текстовом редакторе.

В конфиге CKEditor

```
config.imageUploadUrl = '/IntITA/lesson/CKEUploadImage';
```

Где CKEUploadImage экшн на сервере (написан на Yii Framework. PHP)

```
public function actionCKEUploadImage()
{
    $path = StaticFilesHelper::createLectureImagePath();
    // files storage folder
    $dir = Yii::getpathOfAlias('webroot') . $path;

    $_FILES['upload']['type'] = strtolower($_FILES['upload']['type']);
    if ($_FILES['upload']['type'] == 'image/png'
        || $_FILES['upload']['type'] == 'image/jpg'
        || $_FILES['upload']['type'] == 'image/gif'
        || $_FILES['upload']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
        || $_FILES['upload']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg'
    ) {
        $filename = md5(date('YmdHis')) . $_FILES['upload']['name'];
        $full_path = $dir . $filename;
        $http_path = Config::getBaseUrl().'/images/lecture/' . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $full_path)
      }

   // return ?; 
}
```

Проблема вот в чем - на сервер картинка при перетягивании загружается, но сам плагин возвращает ошибку "Неверный ответ сервера".
Кто подскажет как прикрутить мою загрузку картинки на сервер с отображением этой загрузки в редакторе?